# maas-cli login always returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: authentication, maas

I have a test setup running with a MaaS Server, a JuJu Server and a number of Nodes
in the MaaS Cluster.

After I reinstalled my MaaS Server (and subsequently the JuJu-Core Server) with Saucy 
instead of Precise, certain things definitely improved while, at least one other thing 
seems to be broken now. The `maas-cli`. I always get an error :

```
httplib2.socks.HTTPError, 403, Forbidden.
```

I also created a new MaaS `Key/OAuth` Token, but to no avail. I have a couple of machines, 
that have different number of Disks in the cluster. But they have the same number of CPUs
and the same amount of memory. According to this [article on Juju charm restraints](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-constraints.html).

I can also use tags as constraints in the deployment process to distinguish between the
nodes. As I'm seemingly unable to tag the nodes through the MaaS Web UI, I wanted to
use the `maas-cli`. On precise it worked well, I used it to release nodes etc.
But on Saucy I haven't even once been able to at least login. I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__main__.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/__init__.py", line 46, in main
    options.execute(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/cli.py", line 70, in __call__
    description = fetch_api_description(options.url, options.insecure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/api.py", line 71, in fetch_api_description
    ascii_url(url_describe), "GET", insecure=insecure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maascli/api.py", line 60, in http_request
    return http.request(url, method, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1569, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1316, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1251, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 900, in connect
    self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port) + sa[2:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 424, in connect
    self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/socks.py", line 390, in __negotiatehttp
    raise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
httplib2.socks.HTTPError: (403, 'Forbidden')
```

The maas.log does not hold anything regarding this issue. It holds Error messages about
OAuth and that a request was unauthorized. But that's an 'old' message. No new
messages seem to be written to that log.

```
ERROR 2013-11-22 09:35:37,592 maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 19, in inner_func
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 128, in __call__
    actor, anonymous = self.authenticate(request, rm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 103, in authenticate
    if not authenticator.is_authenticated(request):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api_auth.py", line 57, in is_authenticated
    raise OAuthUnauthorized(error)
OAuthUnauthorized
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it were the `http-proxy`/`https-proxy` environment variables.

As I'm using private IP's for POC, I had to setup `http-proxy`/`https-proxy` environment variables. Especially since `maas-import-pxe-files` needs this.